# Statistics of Remotely Sensed LST values and Weather Station Data

Tags: regression, correlation

I am performing a correlation analysis between:
MODIS Terra and Aqua Satellites LST Data
Landsat 8 LST Data
Weather Stations LST data.

There are 11 combinations of mean MODS Terra and Aqua LST observations reduced over an ROI (E.g. Terra Day -Terra Night, Terra Day-Aqua Night, TerraDay-TerraNight-AquaDay, and so on). I also have LST values recorded from weather stations. So, I take the LST values from one station, calculate the correlation with all combinations of terra and aqua (Joining them first by observation date) and repeat for all stations. Therefore I get 11 sets of correlation values and linear regression equations for each weather station. (I take the mean of pixel values in a 50m buffer around the stations)

Similarly, I have generated values of mean LST over the same ROI using Landsat 8 and performed the correlation analysis with the 11 sets of MODIS data.

For these pairs of observations, I have calculated the coefficient of determination R^2, the RMSD, p-value, and the Standard Error. I am getting p-values very close to zero ( < 0.01 ) in almost all regressions. In terms of the satellite data, I am getting a correlation of around 0.35 (+-1) for all sets of data, and for weather station comparison I am getting a correlation of 0.6-0.8.

My question is how what tests I can perform to check the accuracy of the output statistics? And what else stats (if anything) can I perform to get more insight given the nature of the data?